# How to prove this similarly but changing the hypothesis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the followong statement, which includes already a proof, but changing the hypothesis $P^2 = P$ by dim Im $P^2= $ dim Im $P$ and assuming $V$ is finite dimensional.

[image]

I was trying to prove that dim Im $P^2 = $ dim Im $P$ implies $P^2=P$, but I don't know if that's true. Instaed, I have a proof that dim Im $P^2 = $ dim Im $P$ implies that Im $P ^2 =$ Im $P$ but I'm stuck there, because I cannot use the key step $P(v)=P(w)$ of the proof, instaed I get $P(P(v))=P(w)$, which implies that $P(v) \in$ Ker $P$, but not that $P(v)=0$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption $\dim \operatorname{im} P^2 = \dim \operatorname{im} P$ says that the restriction $P\lvert_{\operatorname{im} P}\colon \operatorname{im} P \to \operatorname{im} P$ is surjective, if $\dim\operatorname{im} P < \infty$. Since an endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space is surjective if and only if it is injective, we have

$$\{0\} = \ker P\lvert_{\operatorname{im} P} = \ker P \cap \operatorname{im} P$$

under the condition that $\dim\operatorname{im} P < \infty$, without needing the finite-dimensionality of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

This is false in general. Chose
$$P = 2\ {\rm id}$$
for a general example assuming ${\rm char\ } \mathbb K \neq 2$ and $V$ being a $\mathbb K$-Vectorspace

Comment: I'm sorry. I had the wrong picture, with something extra to prove. I wanted to prove only one of the two assertions of the previous picture.

Comment: @Twink still after your image you say "I was trying to prove... _[something wrong]_". I gave a counter-example for that something.

Comment: Ok. But as I said "I don't know if that's true", so I didn't use it.

Comment: The latter one is also wrong, consider a rotation.